# How to use Yup context in `oneOf` validation rule?

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I have this form

```js
const form = useForm({
  context: { existingNames },
  mode: 'onChange',
  reValidateMode: 'onChange',
  resolver: yupResolver(validationRules),
  delayError: 600,
});
```

And want to use the `existingNames` context, an array of names, inside the `oneOf` rule.

```js
const validationRules = Yup.object({
  name: Yup.oneOf(existingNames, , 'Name already in use.'), //  ?
})
```

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by writing my own test.

```js
const isUniqueNickname = Yup.string().test(
  'no-duplicate-name',
  'Name already in use.',
  function test(value) {
    // Must not be an arrow function, because yup binds to "this".
    // Note the use of this.options.context to reference context.
    const { existingNames } = this.options.context;
    const foundMatch = existingNames.some((name) => name === value);
    const isValid = !foundMatch;

    return isValid;
  }
);
```